# Select month value in a timestamp field as part of a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I will like to query a MySQL database table that has a timestamp field. The query is a SELECT statement that retrieves, as part of the columns, the month value in the timestamp. At present, I have no idea what to write.

The main reason I'm doing this in MySQL is that I would want to sort the result by that month value.

Perhaps if it's not possible, a PHP solution will be highly welcome.

(It's been a long time I asked any question on SO, so please forgive the formatting. Hope to catch up on it soon.)

Comment: `SELECT MONTH(column) FROM foo`?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. That was quick. I'll try it. Can I ORDER BY month(column)?

Comment: I tried your sample query on my table. It worked but it returned the integer value of the month. I need the name. Can I do it in MySQL? If no, I'll use PHP. Thanks once again

Comment: @afaolek Yes, with `MONTHNAME()` instead of `MONTH()`. Read over the available [MySQL date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: @Michael Thanks, especially for the reference. That did it.